# Matrix differentiation

Tags: r, matrix, derivative

I know the function

```
D(expression( (x^2)),  'x')
```

will give me the derivative of $x^2$ which is $2 \, x$

Whoever when I am trying to take the derivative of the function `exp(1.9 + B %*% X)` using the same function `D`

```
D(expression( (exp(1.9 + B %*% X))),  'x')
```

where $B$ is a $4 \times 1$ matrix and $X$ is a $10 \times 4$ matrix I am getting an error

```
Error in D(expression(exp(1.9 + B %*% X)), "x") : 
Function '`%*%`' is not in the derivatives table
```

Any advise on how to handle this error is much appricated.

Comment: You have some fundamental problems to deal with. For instance, if $B$ really is $4\times 1$ and $X$ is $10\times 4$, then `B%*%X` is not defined. There's also an issue of syntax: `X` and `x` are different in `R`, so even if your attempt were to return without error, it would produce only zeros.  The help page for `D` makes it clear that it doesn't know how to handle `%*%`. Another issue concerns the application of `exp`: `R` will exponentiate the matrix component-by-component, but the *matrix  exponential* does something quite different: which one do you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do matrix differentiation, for far more complicated functions than this, using the ADiMat http://www.sc.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/res/adimat/index.en.jsp automatic differentiator https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation in MATLAB.  You can differentiate almost any differentiable program you write in MATLAB involving matrices or vectors. For instance, most of what's in http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf , plus more. The result will be a program you can use to evaluate the gradient, Jacobian,  or Hessian of the function at whatever input points you provide, not a nice symbolic formula as you have written.

This is just the ticket if you need to supply gradient, Jacobian and/or Hessian to a numerical nonlinear optimizer.  There is a bit of a learning curve, however.

Of course, as whuber points out, your matrices and vectors need to be conformal, as you would need in MATLAB even if you were not (automatically) differentiating.

Comment: If the OP wants symbolic expressions, or wants to understand the basis of these differentiation programs, the references on [this Stack Exchange page](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9891/reference-for-matrix-calculus) would be useful places to start.

Comment: Yes.  I threw a little bone though with my link to the Matrix Cookbook.  If he wants to do things like computing Hessians of eigenvalues though, Matrix Cookbook runs out of gas.  I am not aware of any software which performs symbolic differentiation at a matrix level, for instance, able to perform differentiation as in the Matrix Cookbook.  If you are aware of any such software, please tell us about it.   I think it's eminently doable, that's why I was surprised to not find such a thing when I looked last year.

Comment: Mathematica can at least do [symbolic Jacobians](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5790/how-to-make-jacobian-automatically-in-mathematica), although I typically have trouble relating the list-based structures in Mathematica to standard matrix/vector notation. I guess I don't think like Stephen Wolfram.

Comment: Everyone (Mathematica, MAPLE, MACSYMA/MAXIMA, AXIOM, and plenty more) and their uncle can do symbolic differentiation and produce gradient, Jacobian, Hessian, etc.   But they are not doing it a matrix level.  Let's seem them differentiate the inverse of a matrix without explicitly inverting it and differentiating element by element, resulting in a geometrically exploded mess by dimension 5 or 6. They do not produce an answer like Matrix Cookbook at the matrix level,  That's what I'm talking about..

Comment: I think there are some up and coming tools in Julia which may also be able to do matrix level automatic differentiation, but I'm not sure of their maturity and correctness level as of now.